# Is there a named antipattern for unclear API not exposing the requirements?

Tags: coding-style, anti-patterns

In the source code I'm evaluating ([jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)), there exists java code that can be used like this:

```
JarJarTask fixture = new JarJarTask();
fixture.addConfiguredRule(new Rule());
fixture.execute();
```

Which will throw an exception like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
The <rule> element requires both "pattern" and "result" attributes.
```

Now, to me it is clear that the API is less than optimal here - if the rule element requires these attributes, it should ask for them in the constructor (or provide a Builder or similar that would require them). But I was unable to find coding conventions or java programming recommendations to agree with me.

Is there some specific name for this that I can use to look this up in research, programming literature, style guides? Which terms could I use to find some discussion on this?

Surely it's been discussed somewhere using some terms, but I seem to be unable to find anything.

---

I did find discussion around [constructor injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection) as presented by Kent Beck in Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns and [supported by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorVersusSetterInjection), which, according to [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4483212), makes it "immediately clear what a class requires when it is instantiated, and furthermore it is impossible to instantiate the class without passing in the field’s objects". So that's a starting point at least to find some discussion.

Comment: such a name would be [a matter of opinion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491)

Comment: @gnat there are plenty of bad programming practices that have some canonical names to refer them to. It would be matter of opinion if there isn't any canonical term. So are you saying there isn't one? That would be an answer as well, I guess.

Comment: It's the: API Named After Worse Character in Star Wars Saga Anti-Pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you're going to do here is to state what the API *isn't*, or what it fails to provide.  [Constructor vs. Setter Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ConstructorVersusSetterInjection) is a bit of a side journey, but the principle is sound: write your classes so that it is clear from the constructor arguments exactly what is required to create a fully-formed, functional object.

If you follow best practices in your organization, simply state that *the class fails to follow the practice of describing its instantiation requirements in the constructor.*

**Related**
[Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I read this so that there isn't, which does surprise me a bit.

Comment: Many best practices *don't* have a name.  "put your local variable declarations as close as possible to their first use" doesn't have a name, AFAIK.  "Put braces on their own line" does; it's called ["Allman Style."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style)